# Do native speakers really always pronounce the voiced th as a /ð/?

Tags: pronunciation, phonetics, ipa

In [Can we pronounce the 'th' sound as a d?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/278886/can-we-pronounce-the-th-sound-as-a-d?newreg=a6b2e68fb0bf41958c1d62526a8591b9) one answer explained that native speakers often don't pronounce the voiced th excactly like how it ideally should sound.

What I have noticed over years of observation is that the voiced th is oftentimes pronounced as a [d] sometimes with a hint of /ð/ in it.
This also seems to only be the case for certain words like "the, rather, those and to a lesser extend mother, father etc.)
When you look at sites like [Wikipedia: Pronunciation of English ⟨th⟩](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pronunciation_of_English_%E2%9F%A8th%E2%9F%A9) it will tell you that this is called th-stopping and only occurs in certain accents.
But from my observations it rather seems to be prevalent in almost all accents as well as RP in English.

There have been similar questions on forums like [Quora](https://www.quora.com/Is-it-acceptable-to-pronounce-an-initial-th-as-d-For-actual-th-the-tongue-is-in-between-the-upper-and-lower-teeth-For-d-and-t-the-tongue-is-behind-the-upper-teeth) where the general consesus seems to be that pronouncing the voiced th as a [d] is an unusual thing mostly reserved to accent and non native speakers, however almost all native speakers that I have ever spoken to or heard use the [d] pronunciation for the voiced th in one way or the other.

Before you write your answer note that:

I am only talking about the **voiced** th. The unvoiced th as far as I can tell is always pronounced as a /θ/.

I am fully able to pronounce the voiced th as /ð/. However doing so often feels stiff like as if you pronounce all the T letters in "important" as true T instead of omitting some or using stop T.

Some people will now use a word like "bathe" and write about how ridiculous it would be to pronounce it as "bade". This is why I say that this only seems to be the case for certain words containing the voiced th like (the, those, that, other etc.) while in other words like (bathe, breathe, loathe etc.) the voiced th seems to be indeed always pronounced as a /ð/.

Comment: Most people don't really pay attention to what they actually say; they believe they've said everything correctly (whatever that means locally), and will disagree when told they've pronounced or not pronounced something. This is normal. There is always a difference between what people intend to say and what they actually do say.

Comment: And, no, native speakers do not always pronounce /ð/. They frequently delete it, or use a stop /d/ instead.

Comment: Welcome to English Language & Usage. As interesting as this topic may be, it is possibly too broad to answer in our format; it would depend on the  dialect, regional pronunciation, social register, etc. I am voting to close, but if you can find a way to restrict the post to make it more on-topic I will withdraw the close vote. In the meantime +1

Comment: Function words very often have weak forms. People pronounce *and* as /ən/, *because* as /bəkəz/, *for* as /fər/ when they wouldn't make the same changes in pronunciations to the words *band*, *gauze*, and *four*. For function words beginning with /ð/ people often have /d/ in their weak forms. But you can only use weak forms in some situations; only people speaking dialects with th-stopping will say *It's over dare* and not *It's over there*.

Comment: Another related previous question: [/z/ + /ð/ = /zdð/?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/419044/z-ð-zdð)

Comment: Agreed with @Cascabel_StandWithUkraine_ good question not easily answerable here.