# When is it OK to pronounced a voiced th like a /d/ instead of a /ð/?

Tags: pronunciation, phonetics, ipa

As I learned in [Do native speakers really always pronounce the voiced th as a /ð/?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/590660/do-native-speakers-really-always-pronounce-the-voiced-th-as-a-%c3%b0?noredirect=1#comment1483158_590660) native speakers sometimes pronounce the voiced th as a /d/ instead of a /ð/ like in the words "the", "those", "others", "that", "rather", etc.

However this apparently only happens in certain situations.

What I am talking about here is **not** th-stopping as observed in some regional dialects, but instead the phenomenom that occurs for almost all native English speakers regardless of their region.

So when is it OK to pronounced a voiced th like a /d/ instead of a /ð/?

Comment: You should strive to pronounce it as /ð/ not /d/. Just because a native speaker does something lazily, or mumbles or misspeaks doesn't mean you should try and copy them. There isn't a rigid rule you should follow, other than this one.

Comment: Actually, the rule is that you should imitate native speakers, not that you should try to pronounce from the spelling. Of course, you may not have native speakers to talk to. But movies with subtitles give an idea of how the spelling is sposta be pronounced.

Comment: The problem with pronouncing everything like in the dictionary is that it usually sounds too rigid and unnatural, which is why native speakers often don't do it.

Comment: I'm perfectly okay with a /d/ in *the, there, that*. But *udders* and *radder* sound very much like a regional dialect to me.

Answer (score 1):

> What I am talking about here is not *th*-stopping as observed in some regional dialects, but instead the phenomenon that occurs for almost all native English speakers regardless of their region.

No such phenomenon exists, to my knowledge. For my part (being in the Northeast US), I don't pronounce /ð/ as [d] even in weak forms of *the, there, that,* even when speaking very rapidly.